# Meteor findOne to return the value in a given field

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor collection which has a document, I need to get the value referenced by a given field name.
I was reading the docs and few online examples but they return the cursor for a given field and value pair.  Not what I am after.

On the server, I tried `collectionName.findOne('fieldName');` which returned undefined. Thanks

Comment: If you need specific document, then just use: collectionName.findOne({fieldname : 'fieldvalue'}) otherwise, just use collectionName.findOne() and it will give you the first value.

Comment: Are you asking how to search by a property's value, or how to limit the data returned to a particular field, by property name? It sound like the latter. If so `collectionName.findOne({}, {fields: {fieldName:1}})` should to the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can send only selected field on meteor.

```
collectionName.findOne({},{fields:{_id:1}})

<field>: <1 or true>    Specify the inclusion of a field.
<field>: <0 or false>   Specify the suppression of the field.
```

Here your output will be :: Object {_id: "mbhQBFDFQ6z6BP2Rc"}.
You can replace the _id with any other fieldName. For selected multiple filed just separate the fieldNames with comma.

The fields work for find as well as findOne.
For more about fields you can check [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

For sending only single field using findOne you can directly user

> collectionName.findOne().fieldName